# Which PhoneGap Build Version on iOS

Tags: cordova

Aside from the javascript file called `<script src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>`

Which indicates that the library 2.7.0 is the library, but is there another way to tell.

I'm looking to upgrade some older Phonegap libraries to 2.7, but I'm not sure which library they are based on.

Answer (score 0):

goto cordova-2.7.0.js and in the first few lines is the commit id that looks like this..

```
// commit cd29cf0f224ccf25e9d422a33fd02ef67d3a78f4
```

go google this "[git commit cd29cf0f224ccf25e9d422a33fd02ef67d3a78f4](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=cd29cf0f224ccf25e9d422a33fd02ef67d3a78f4&oq=cd29cf0f224ccf25e9d422a33fd02ef67d3a78f4&aqs=chrome.0.57.1220j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=git%20commit%20cd29cf0f224ccf25e9d422a33fd02ef67d3a78f4&oq=git%20commit%20cd29cf0f224ccf25e9d422a33fd02ef67d3a78f4&gs_l=serp.3...24195.26403.0.26658.11.11.0.0.0.0.119.877.10j1.11.0...0.0.0..1c.1.16.psy-ab.vfM8VUrl1Kk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.bmk&fp=811f8b22bb36eb43&biw=1600&bih=742)" and click on the first result. This will show the tagging number for the release. The tagging number is the release version

Comment: Interesting I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

Newer Cordova library files contain the build info, like

```
var CORDOVA_JS_BUILD_LABEL = '2.8.0-0-g6208c95';
```

You can read the version info inside of your app, too.

```
device.cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cordova API to receive the version:

```
var name = device.cordova;
```

It returns the version of Cordova running on the device. [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.cordova)